# AFNetworking failing in java web service

Tags: java, objective-c, afnetworking-2

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL here`URLWithString:@"http://testing.appspot.com/json/ListingBusinessService/"];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

    httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"params":@"women",@"params" : @"women", @"params":@"women"};

    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

    [httpClient 
          postPath:@"getNewArrivalProductDetailsWithPaginationForIosApp"
          parameters:params 
           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,id responseObject) 
               {
                  NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
                }
                 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
                 {
                     NSLog(@"%@",error);
                    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Data"
                                                                  message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error]
                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [av show];
                 }
     ];
```

I am getting following error while executing above code like AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey , i guess i missing something in parameters, please suggest me in this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the context of this code? What solutions did you try? Please elaborate your question in order to receive better help!

Comment: What's the error? What's not working?

Comment: i am getting error like AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey , in error its printing entire json, but in the failure block

Comment: Anyone knows how to fix this please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

After calling this URL with curl from the commandline I'd say the problem is that the response content type is text/plain instead of application/json. A AFJSONRequestOperation expects the application/json ContentType.

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-TraceUrl: /appstats/details?time=1390399595248&type=json
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Wed, 22 Jan 2014 14:06:35 GMT
* Server Google Frontend is not blacklisted
< Server: Google Frontend
< Cache-Control: private
< Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, And i have updated the code with application/json, Still i am getting failure message

Comment: I just tried again to access that URL again and now I get a HTTP302 and contentType ist text/html